# Swift - UINavigation Controller becoming nil

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem with my `UINavigationController` when I try to push another controller.

**AppDelegate**

```
 let testViewController:ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController = ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController();
    self.navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: testViewController);

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);
    self.window!.rootViewController = navController;
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible();

    return true
```

**ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController**

```
class ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController:UIViewController {

// Controls
var proximityIntroductionView:ProximityQuestionsIntroductionView!;

// Load components when the view is loaded
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    print("nav in viewDidLoad : \(self.navigationController)");
    //Hide Nav bar
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;
    // Set view
    self.proximityIntroductionView = ProximityQuestionsIntroductionView(frame: self.view.frame);
    self.view = self.proximityIntroductionView;
}

func start(){
    print(self);
    print("start in controller");
    let nextController = ProximityQuestionsProgressViewController();
    print("nav in start : \(self.navigationController)");
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextController, animated: true);

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I call `start` from my `ProximityQuestionsIntroductionView` when a button is clicked. 
In the log I see "*nav in start : nil*" and the controller doesn't change.

For more info :

- self is really the `ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController`.
- the navigation bar is really hidden

So the navigation controller is ok in `viewDidLoad` but not in the other function.

Can someone tell me why ?

Thanks!

**EDIT : AppDelegate**

```
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProximityIntroduction");
    self.navController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavigationController") as! UINavigationController;
    self.navController?.setViewControllers([initialViewController], animated: false)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navController;
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
```

I add navigation Controller to the story Board and change the ID. But I still have a `nil` value for the `UINavigationController`in the function `start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the view.

Doing this :

```
// Set view
    self.proximityIntroductionView = ProximityQuestionsIntroductionView(frame: self.view.frame);
    self.view = self.proximityIntroductionView;
```

causes the problem. I don't know exactly why but putting all the UIView in the controller directly solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController")
    navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:initialViewController )
    navigationController?.setViewControllers([initialViewController], animated: false)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Put Story board id for this ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController

Comment: I'm trying to do all my project without the storyboard so I've got a : 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x16ead2f0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController''

Comment: So are you using xib for design?

Comment: I'm doing it all programmatically. It's a project which has been started by other people and I just can't read the storyboard it's a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You must mark the window and navController variables as optional:

```
var window : UIWindow?
var navController : UINavigationController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    let testViewController:ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController = ProximityQuestionsIntroductionViewController();

    self.navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: testViewController);

  if let window = window {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);
    self.window!.rootViewController = navController;
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible();
  }
    return true
}
```

If you created the project from an Xcode template:
Remove the key-value pair for key "Main storyboard file base name" from Info.plist.
Delete the storyboard file Main.storyboard.

Comment: That's how my code was when I first post the question. It doesn't work, self.navigationController is stil nil in the function start of the first controller.